# Initiate toggling div n secs after page is rendered

Tags: jquery

I am using the below code to toggle a div on my main web page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if ($("div[id='feature-content']").is(":visible")) {
            $("div[id='feature-content']").hide();
            $("div[id='feature-content']").slideToggle(9000).delay(4000);
        }

        $("div[id='feature-content']").slideToggle(9000).delay(4000);
    }
    ,
    5000
    );      
});
```

With the above code the following happens:

- The div "feature-content" appears immediately once the page is rendered (DOM is ready)
- It stays visible for 5 secs,
- then disappears
- then toggling starts.

What I want to achieve is:

- The div "feature-content" should be hidden when the page is rendered.
- After 5 secs, the toggling should begin.

I tried to add the css style "display:hidden" to the div, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: I also tried window.load() function, I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part after "the following happens" is exactly what I think should happen, from inspecting the code.  Try just this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("div[id='feature-content']").hide().delay(5000).slideToggle(9000);
  });
```

**EDIT**  I think the OP wants it to pause, slide into view, pause, then slide out of view, which would be this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("div[id='feature-content']").hide().delay(5000).slideToggle().delay(9000).slideToggle();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Malvolio, I am trying to achieve the toggle effect like you see sometimes on cnn.com showing an advertisement on a panel that scroll down, pushing the entire web page down,  and then scrolling back up restoring normal view. I modified code as you suggested, but now the panel does not scroll back up.

Comment: @user765081 -- yeah, there was no reason for it to slide back up.  See the new version of the code.

Comment: Malvolio: Thank you very much! Works like a charm!, I only have to modify the time intervals and that is easy enough for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `display:none` not hidden